# Setting Wi-fi Connection

Tags: iphone, ios, wifi, preferences, reachability

I am new to iPhone development. I am developing an application in which I am using Settings.bundle  which allows user to ON\OFF Wi-fi connection.
Is there any way to turn ON\OFF device wi-fi when user changes settings from application settings???
I want to turn ON\OFF wi-fi based on changes to settings bundle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not the job of your app to connect to the wireless! You can't alter the wifi settings of the iPhone from inside an application.

As far as I know, maybe jailbroken phones can do more.

You just Check Weather your phone is connected with Wifi or other network so 
http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/Reachability/ will be best place to start with. Have a look at the sample provided by Apple.